# Using `subprocess.run` with an argument that includes a space

Tags: python, subprocess

When using `subprocess.run` in Python, how do I execute a command where one of the arguments includes a space?

For example, I want to create a file with the name `test file` (inc. space). In the shell you would do:

```sh
touch 'test file'
```

Using `subprocess.run` in Python I have tried:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["touch", "'test file'") # Creates a file called `'test file'` (inc. quotes)
subprocess.run(["touch", "test\ file") # Creates a file called `test\ me`
subprocess.run(["touch", "test", "file") # Creates two files `test` and `file`
subprocess.run(["touch", "'test", "file'") # Creates two files `'test` and `file'`
```

Comment: The whole *point* of supplying a list of arguments to the various `subprocess` functions is that you don't have to worry about delimiting them - each argument is taken exactly as it is.

Comment: Is there a *really good reason* why you are calling out to the shell to create a file? You can do it much more simply by calling `open()` in Python, and that avoids any puzzles about how what you pass to `subprocess()` gets parsed by the shell.

Comment: @jasonharper That wasn't clear to me before (even after looking at the subprocess docs) but is now

Comment: @BoarGules my real use case is not to create a file. I'm just using this as a easy example to explain the problem

Answer (score 2):

No need to use quotes to specify an argument that includes a space as its treated as a string literal, just do:

```
subprocess.run(["touch", "test file"])
```

That creates a file called `test file`.

Comment: That's true for subprocess.run(), but notice that when using os.system() you use quotes just as running in shell